# How to label 3D plot axis using jzy3d library?

Tags: java, jogl, jzy3d

I was wondering if anybody knows how to assign labels for the (x,y,z) axis using jzy3d 3D plotting library.

I have tried to use such assignment:

```
chart.getView().setAxeLabels("","","");
```

From here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jzy3d/6nkwF8C01Do

But it does not work.

Any ideas how to do that as by default they show up unassigned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can learn a lot by looking at the documentation, but I agree that their tutorials are lacking a lot of basic information.

```
chart.getAxeLayout().setXAxeLabel("");
chart.getAxeLayout().setYAxeLabel("");
chart.getAxeLayout().setZAxeLabel("");
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked just perfect, even though it was obvious could not find it!